# parsing Json in Android Studio when result is empty

Tags: json, android-studio, gson

I try to load datas from a Json that is on my server to my smartphone.

When the json is like this, it works and i get the label "spanishguitar":

```
{"file": "image.jpg", "objects": [{"bbox": [611, 82, 1231, 1265], "label": "spanishguitar", "prob": 0.991}]}
```

Here is my code:

```
public void updateLabel() {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpRequestParams());
                HttpGet getJson = new HttpGet(SERVER_ADRESS + "objects.json");
                HttpResponse jsonResponse = client.execute(getJson);
                if (200 == jsonResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
                    InputStream inputStream = jsonResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                    String json = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
                    JsonResult jsonResult = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonResult.class);
                        instrumentname = jsonResult.objects.get(0).label;
```

But sometimes the json is empty like this:

```
{"file": "image.jpg", "objects": []}
```

So my plan is that if `objects == null` to get something like:

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uuuups, itś empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Do you know how to parse the json, so that i get a message in the case of an empty "objects"?

Thank you!

---

Now it works. Here is my code:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private void empty() throws IOException {

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpRequestParams());
        HttpGet getJson = new HttpGet(SERVER_ADRESS + "objects.json");
        HttpResponse jsonResponse = client.execute(getJson);

            InputStream inputStream = jsonResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            String json = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);


            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

            JsonElement element = parser.parse(String.valueOf(json));
            JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject();
            JsonArray objects = obj.getAsJsonArray("objects");
            if (objects == null || objects.size() == 0) {
                /////////////
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        noResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Identification failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }});
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            } else {
               updateLabel();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

'Empty' is not 'null'.You can use

```
ArrayUtils.isEmpty(objects)
```

or

```
objects == null || objects.length() == 0
```

to detect whether you got an empty objects.

I writed a demo for you:

```
import com.google.gson.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
//        JsonElement element= parser.parse("{\"file\": \"image.jpg\", \"objects\": []}");
        JsonElement element= parser.parse("{\"file\": \"image.jpg\", \"objects\": [{\"bbox\": [611, 82, 1231, 1265], \"label\": \"spanishguitar\", \"prob\": 0.991}]}");
        JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray objects = obj.getAsJsonArray("objects");
        if(objects == null || objects.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("objects is empty");
        }else{
            JsonObject firstObj = objects.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println("objects[0].label="+firstObj.get("label"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thank you! but how to "find" this object? Something like:     object= jsonResult.objects(0); ?

Comment: You can use jsonResult.get("objects").